# How to establish unicast or multicast communication in veins_inet?

Tags: networking, omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

In veins_inet example I need to send accident packets only for some vehicles (nodes), but by default it's taking broadcast in veinsInetApplication.cc so how can I change it to multicast?

SendPacket method was derived from veinsInetApplicationBase.cc. If I change anything there then I'm getting errors. Default port is 9001 so I can't change there also. so can I get any solutions for this?

[image: Send Packet Method]

VeinsInetApplication.cc

[[image: Default Port][2]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Vanet nodes unicast or multicast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528958/how-to-make-vanet-nodes-unicast-or-multicast)

Comment: Hello sir. Thanks for responding. But no need of Veins there?